# Vanilla Javascript change image when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change my logo into white when in mobile? But I already have below code for on scroll I am using vanilla javascript. I have the dark and light logo. Its working when on scroll but don't know how to add script for width mobile

```
 addEventListener('scroll', (event) => { });

onscroll = (event) => {
 
  const logoDark = document.querySelector('.nav-logo');
  const logoLight = document.querySelector('.nav-logo-light');

  logoDark.classList.add("show");
  logoLight.classList.add("hide");


  if (window.scrollY > 100) {
    logoDark.classList.add("hide");
    logoLight.classList.add("show");

    for (let i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
      navItems[i].classList.add('light-text');
    }
  }

  else if (window.scrollY < 100) {
    logoDark.classList.remove('hide');
    logoLight.classList.remove("show");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media-query` in javascript *can also be used in CSS as well*

Here's a snippet:

```
function scrollFunction(isMobile) {
  if (!isMobile) { 
   // If this is a desktop screen add your logic for desktop
  } else {
   // else if this is a mobile screen add logic for mobile
  }
}

var matchMedia =  window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)") // or whatever you consider mobile width for your use case.
scrollFunction(matchMedia.matches) // Call listener function at run time
matchMedia.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: do i need a new image for that? as my JS telling to that image needs to hide on scroll